# AngularJS Simple Signature Pad Directive (without jQuery)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

With the help of stackoverflow i got me a simple canvas signature directive. The problem is that it works with mouse events (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove) but is not working with touch events (touchstart,touchmove,touchend). I have ngTouch in my main app module and in the module that holds the directive. I hope you can help me. Here's the code:

```
var sig = angular.module('signature', ['ngTouch']);

sig.directive("mjav", ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');

            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
            var tempCanvas = document.createElement('nanavas');

            // variable that decides if something should be drawn on mousemove
            var drawing = false;

            // the last coordinates before the current move
            var lastX;
            var lastY;

            element.on('touchstart', function (event) {
                if (event.offsetX !== undefined) {
                    lastX = event.offsetX;
                    lastY = event.offsetY;
                } else {
                    lastX = event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
                    lastY = event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
                }

                // begins new line
                ctx.beginPath();

                drawing = true;
            });
            element.on('touchmove', function (event) {
                if (drawing) {
                    // get current mouse position
                    if (event.offsetX !== undefined) {
                        currentX = event.offsetX;
                        currentY = event.offsetY;
                    } else {
                        currentX = event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
                        currentY = event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
                    }

                    draw(lastX, lastY, currentX, currentY);

                    // set current coordinates to last one
                    lastX = currentX;
                    lastY = currentY;
                }
            });

            $document.on('touchend', function (event) {
                // stop drawing
                drawing = false;
            });

            // canvas reset
            function reset() {
                element[0].width = element[0].width;
            }

            function draw(lX, lY, cX, cY) {
                // line from
                ctx.moveTo(lX, lY);
                // to
                ctx.lineTo(cX, cY);
                // color
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
                // draw it
                ctx.stroke();
           }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: canvas work great on mobile devices also, why do you need touch events?

Comment: This is ment for simple signatures. I need touch events so i can draw on the canvas. The above code works with mouse events (drawing works on desktop) but not with touch events.

Comment: Ok so I've established that TOUCH events do work! The trouble has to be with drawing. But what? When i use mouse events everything works perfectly. Is offsetx propertie added differently for touchevents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone will need a simple signature directive for AngularJS this is what I came up with in the end:

```
var sig = angular.module('signature', []);

sig.controller('signatureCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clearVal = 0;
    $scope.saveVal = 0;

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.clearVal += 1; //On this value change directive clears the context
    }

    $scope.saveToImage = function () { 
        $scope.saveVal = 1; //On this value change directive saves the signature
    }
}]);

sig.directive("signatureDir", ['$document', '$log', '$rootScope', function ($document, $log, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');

            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 30;

            // the last coordinates before the current move
            var lastPt;

            function getOffset(obj) {
                return { left: 15, top: 116 }; //Got a fixed offset
            }

            attrs.$observe("value", function (newValue) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            });

            attrs.$observe("saveVal", function (newValue, dnid) {
                var imagedata = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
                $rootScope.signatureTemp.push({'dnid':dnid, 'signature':imagedata});
            });

            element.on('touchstart', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                ctx.fillRect(e.touches[0].pageX - getOffset(element).left, e.touches[0].pageY - getOffset(element).top, 2, 2);
                lastPt = { x: e.touches[0].pageX - getOffset(element).left, y: e.touches[0].pageY - getOffset(element).top };
            });
            element.on('touchmove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (lastPt != null) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(lastPt.x, lastPt.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX - getOffset(element).left, e.touches[0].pageY - getOffset(element).top);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                lastPt = { x: e.touches[0].pageX - getOffset(element).left, y: e.touches[0].pageY - getOffset(element).top };
            });

            element.on('touchend', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                lastPt = null;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="signatureCtrl">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 15px;">Signature</h3>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <canvas saveVal="{{ saveVal }}" value="{{ clearVal }}" style="border: 1px solid black;" id="canvas1" width="200" height="200" signatureDir></canvas>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Save</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If anyone can see some bad code in here please correct me!

Comment: It was for my own custom logic in the app. It has nothing to do with canvas or drawing. It's the ID of the document I'm appending the signature to. I'm having a temp array and in there i save signatures by document id. The code is a direct copy of the code I used in my app.

Comment: @Zoneh I am trying to use your directive but everytime i am getting blank image. Instead of pushing dataurl to signaturetemp  , i am broadcasting it and getting on controller. But data url always shows blank image.

Comment: In the saveToImage() function change the code to  $scope.saveVal += 1 to support multiple clear and save button clicks.

Comment: Not Working as well for me. No Mark is being drawn.